# Confidence intervals for proportions and independence

Tags: confidence-interval, independence, multinomial-distribution

Suppose a company sells various products at different prices. I would like to compute confidence intervals for the contribution of each product to overal sales, preferably in terms of currency (e.g., for each \$100 in sales, \$xx are from product A), or alternatively in terms of numbers sold (e.g., for each 100 units sold, xx units are product A).

My idea was to model this with a multinomial distribution, but the confidence intervals I know assume independence of observations, and I see three possible violations of this assumption for the above problem:

1. The dollars spent on a single unit of one product are not independent.
2. There are hard dependencies between some of the products, e.g., suppose that one product is an extended warranty for another product that cannot be sold separately.
3. There are soft dependencies as well, e.g., the sale of an electronic device will almost certainly lead to the sale of the corresponding power chord, even though both products can be sold separately.

I suppose the first point means that I will have to settle for proportions in terms of numbers rather than currency. But do the second and third point prevent the use of something like the method of Sison and Glaz [1] that is implemented in R's `MultinomCI` function? If so, is there something else I can do?

I am not a statistician by trade, so I apologize if there is a well-known answer to my question that I did not find due to lack of context or terminology. I find it difficult sometimes to reconcile the mathematical definition of independence with practical examples.

[1] Sison, C.P and Glaz, J. (1995) Simultaneous confidence intervals and sample size determination for multinomial proportions. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 90:366-369.